# OpenLayers 2 Cluster Strategy with OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, clustering

I am digging into clustering strategies with Open Layers 2. Looking at the example [OpenLayers2 Cluster Strategy Threshold](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/strategy-cluster-threshold.html), I was able to get it working. Unfortunately I am working with OSM, and the example is not working as expected by replacing the appropriate line in the code example:

```
 /*var base = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS", 
                 "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                {layers: 'basic'}
            );
 */
 var base = new OpenLayers.Layers.OSM();
```

It results in looking at only one circle instead of many. Only when I start zooming in, more and more circles do appear. Why is it different when I am using OSM? Which settings have to be taken care of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the OSM-Layer uses another CRS than the random points. A quick fix is to transform the created points in the corresponding loop:

```
features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(px, py).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857")), {x: px, y: py}
));
```